# ASP.NET Page Inheritance and Overriding onInit

Tags: asp.net

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    var template = LoadControl(Path);
    if (template == null)
        throw new Exception("Could not located the Template");



    var templateControl = template.FindControl("_placeHolder");
    if (templateControl == null)
        throw new Exception("Could not located the Place Holder");

    templateControl.Controls.Add(_container);

    //This doesnt Work
    for (var i = 0; i < template.Controls.Count;i++ )
    {
        var myControl = template.Controls[i];
        Controls.Add(myControl);
    }
    //This works
    for (var i = 0; i < template.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        var myControl = template.Controls[0];
        template.Controls.Remove(myControl);
        Controls.Add(myControl);
    }

}
```

This is just a Tutorial I am working on. The question is Why does the Second for loop display the output on the page and the first one does not. I do comment out one of them to test this. What exactly am i missing and why do i need to remove the control?

Comment: Are you really sure that the title is related to your question?! A better one: "How to copy single controls from UserControl to the Page?"

Comment: You can have only one control with its unique ID in the page. Weird that you don't get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

What I see from your code is

```
for (var i = 0; i < template.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    var myControl = template.Controls[0];
    template.Controls.Remove(myControl);
    Controls.Add(myControl);
}
```

This loop (Second one) doesn't really have any use.
It just removes the same control each time, as there is no use of "i". Every time it removes Controls[0], and re-add it to the Controls.

Hope it helps.
Don't forget to upvote it if it solves you problem.
Thanks.. :)